# How to parse invalid HTML with Perl?

Tags: html, perl, parsing, html-parsing

I maintain a database of articles with HTML formatting. Unfortunately the editors who wrote articles didn't know proper HTML, so they often have written stuff like:

```
<div class="highlight"><html><head></head><body><p>Note that ...</p></html></div>
```

I tried using `HTML::TreeBuilder` to parse this HTML but after parsing it and dumping the resulting tree, all the elements between `<div class="highlight">...</div>` are gone. I'm left with just `<div class="highlight"></div>`.

The editors often have also done things like:

```
<div class="article"><style>@font-face {   font-family: "Cambria"; }</style>Article starts here</div>
```

Parsing this with `HTML::TreeBuilder` results in empty `<div class="article"></div>` again.

Any ideas how to approach this broken HTML and actually make sense out of it?

Comment: Have you tried looking at it as xml? It may not be valid html, but you might be able to pick it apart using xpath.

Comment: @BartonChittenden Good luck with that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would first run it through [HTML::Tidy](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML%3a%3aTidy):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;
use HTML::Tidy;

my $html = <<EO_HTML;
<div class="highlight"><html><head></head>
<body><p>Note that ...</p></html>
</div>
EO_HTML

my $tidy = HTML::Tidy->new;

print $tidy->clean( $html );
```

Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta name="generator" content="tidyp for Windows (v1.04), see www.w3.org">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="highlight">
<p>Note that ...</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can control the output by setting various configuration options.

Then, feed the cleaned HTML through a parser.

Otherwise, you can try building a tree one-step-at-a-time using [HTML::TokeParser::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML%3a%3aTokeParser%3a%3aSimple) or even just [HTML::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML%3a%3aParser), but I believe that way lies insanity.

Keep in mind that a parser that tries to build a tree representation will be stricter than a stream parser that just recognizes various elements as it sees them.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use [Marpa::HTML](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Marpa%3A%3AHTML), which is a high level HTML parser, allowing extremely liberal parsing.  It can parse even invalid HTML using technique called *ruby slippers* by its author; Marpa::HTML adds element that should be there.

See an example of reformatting, prettifying and making valid of example invalid HTML in [How to Parse HTML](http://blogs.perl.org/users/jeffrey_kegler/2011/11/how-to-parse-html.html) blog post by Jeffrey Kegler, author of Marpa parser and Marpa::HTML.

Answer (score 1):

[XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aLibXML) is also, perhaps surprisingly, good at this kind of clean-up if used correctly. It's also extremely fast; and deep/flexible once you get past its learning curve.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strictures;
use XML::LibXML;

my @craptastic = ( '<div class="article"><style>@font-face{ font-family: "Cambria" }</style>Article starts here</div>',
                   '<div class="highlight"><html><head></head><body><p>Note that ...</p></html></div>' );

# The inline setting of recover_silently is broken/non-functional so
# we do the method calls to set.
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
$parser->recover_silently(1);
$parser->keep_blanks(1);

for my $crap ( @craptastic )
{
    my $doc = $parser->load_html( string => $crap );

    # Optional example for killing style tags not in the <head/>
    $_->parentNode->removeChild($_) for $doc->findnodes("//body//style");

    print $/, $crap, $/;
    my ( $body ) = $doc->findnodes("//body");
    print "-" x 60, $/;
    print $_->serialize(1) for $body->childNodes;
    print $/, $/;
}
```

Gives you–

```
<div class="article"><style>@font-face{ font-family: "Cambria" }</style>Article starts here</div>
------------------------------------------------------------
<div class="article">Article starts here</div>


<div class="highlight"><html><head></head><body><p>Note that ...</p></html></div>
------------------------------------------------------------
<div class="highlight">
  <p>Note that ...</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like [Tag soup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_soup).
As another approach, you can also use the java program "[html-tagsoup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/)" from within your perl program (with backticks, for instance).  It can be called as a standalone program like this.

```
java -jar tagsoup-1.2.1 [option ...] [file ...]
```

HTML::Tidy used to be better or more flexible , I think.